# Is there way to write GAE JUnit for Google OAuth2 test

Tags: google-app-engine, junit, google-oauth

I search around the Google and not that I know of... I don't even see any Dev libraries availble for this as well. Any comment please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test the Google OAuth process in your unit tests because it is requiring a third party application (Google) to do it.
So it is not possible.